# Get current url from Chrome outside of browser

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible for an app running outside of Google Chrome to determine the the currently selected url (for the currently selected tab)? I was thinking more along the lines of an app developed using Chromium that needs to obtain the current url from Chrome. Since Google Chrome is based on Chromium, maybe there is something that lets Chrome and a Chromium app communicate with each other? Of course, due to security issues, I would suspect that even if this is possible, it would require some form of authorization on the part of Google Chrome by the user to allow the url to be read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: [chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli) (it works with OS X only)